# Google Analytics Tracker Integration

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am running into an issue with one of the methods that is supposed to be called on the Tracker object.

```
tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
```

**Error:**

> The method enableExceptionReporting(boolean) is undefined for the type
>   Tracker

**Does anyone know exactly how I can resolve this issue?**

I am following the Google Documentation.

> https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#manifest

**Imports:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
```

**OnCreate():**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    InitApplication.context = getApplicationContext();

    analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);

    tracker = analytics.newTracker("UA-XXXXX-Y"); // Replace with actual tracker/property Id
    tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
    tracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);

}
```

Comment: Please show some more code, it seems the tracker has not yet been loaded when you call it, but without context it's not possible to determine why that is. Did you put your tracking code at the end of the body?

Comment: Did you `import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;` ?

Comment: @donfuxx might be right, your might be using a wrong import. And without code, its difficult to identify.

Comment: I am using the correct imports from what I can tell. I posted the only code I am using so far.